Oracle Forms 6i, information deletes itself
I started working in a public water treatment company, where they use Oracle forms 6i to generate reports, they are in the process of making an upgrade to the system, but something strange happens with the current one, when entering the records (daily, monthly, etc) and save them apparently correctly, without notice suddenly they are deleted without apparent reason, discarding that someone is deleting them, can there be any bug or internal error that deletes the existing information even though it is saved, any suggestions?

Good explanation, but we are going to need all the coding details to even begin.  Alas, its in the form "its broke, why?" so we need to pop the hood and find out.

Although it was working before, what makes you think its saving now when it instead deletes the data?  When you say delete, you mean the forms depopulate with the values?  Is the data in the oracle database when you do the insert?

I guess I don't understand what part is "deleted" do you mean the form had the values, but after you submit the form, the form is empty but the database has the values, so it was inserted?  But by them not appearing in the form you are calling it "deleted" ?

You said, "....can there be any bug...".  Are you aware that 6i came out in 2000 and was desupported in approximately 2006 or so.  The latest version is 12.2.1.19.  Likey hundreds or thousands of bugs have been fixed since that old version was released.  That said, if the app(s) was working before AND nothing has changed since, then you can assume it has always been this way.  If there have been code changes, software updates (including the DB), or any other changes, it is possible any one or more of those changes is causing the problem.
